# JavaScript drag SVG shape is not smooth

Tags: javascript, html, performance, animation, svg

Drag of SVG shape is not as smooth as drag of icons on a desktop.
Is it possible to drag SVG shape in browser as smooth as native system animations?

This example I try in Chrome browser in windows.
Even a page with single shape is not filling as smooth as system animations.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #diagram {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            user-select: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <svg id="diagram" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        style="touch-action: none; background-color: #fff; display:block;">
        <circle id="crcl" r="60" fill="#ff6600" stroke="#fff" />
        
    </svg>
    <script type="module">
        const crcl = document.getElementById('crcl');
        let isDown;
        let delta;

        crcl.onpointerdown = function(evt) {
            crcl.setPointerCapture(evt.pointerId);
            isDown = true;
        };

        crcl.onpointermove = function(evt) {
            if(!isDown) {return;}
            if(!delta){
                const shapePosition = svgPositionGet(crcl);
                delta = {
                    x: shapePosition.x - evt.clientX,
                    y: shapePosition.y - evt.clientY
                };
            }

            svgPositionSet(crcl, {
                x: delta.x + evt.clientX,
                y: delta.y + evt.clientY
            });
        };

        crcl.onpointerup = function() {
            isDown = false;
            delta = null;
        };


        // helpers

        function ensureTransform(svgEl, transform, svg) {
            let tr = first(svgEl.transform.baseVal, tt => tt.type === transform);
            if (!tr) {
                tr = (svgEl.ownerSVGElement || svg).createSVGTransform();
                svgEl.transform.baseVal.appendItem(tr);
            }
            return tr;
        }

        function svgPositionGet(svgEl) {
            const mtx = ensureTransform(svgEl, SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE).matrix;
            return {
                x: mtx.e,
                y: mtx.f
            };
        }

        function svgPositionSet(svgEl, position, svg) {
            ensureTransform(svgEl, SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE, svg).setTranslate(position.x, position.y);
        }

        function first(iterable, filter) {
            for (const el of iterable) {
                if (!filter || filter(el)) { return el; }
            }
            return null;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Chrome 'pointermove' consider requestAnimationFrame, so it is not the case.

Comment: To me this feels as smooth as it could get, on Win Chrome. Voting to close since we can reproduce. Did you try the behavior here? Do you experience the jankyness here too? If so, could it be just that your chrome is flooded with hundred tabs open or something?

Comment: Also, even tough it should be prefectly fine for a small amount of shapes,  note that SVG manipulations are not very performent.